# How to run one feature file following with another feature file?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I have 2 feature files i.e `userstoryteacher1.feature` and `userstoryteacher2.feature` . Basicaly `userstoryteacher1.feature` have the steps where it has 2 tags `@Dev` and `@QA`.

I want to run the feature files in following way :-

1. If i pass the `@Dev`,`@tagteacher` in Cucumber class  then it should pick the dev url to open the page with crentials.
2. If i pass the `@QA`,`@tagteacher` in Cucumber class then it should pick the qa url to open the page with credentials.

   ```
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import com.optum.synergy.common.ui.controller.WebController;
   import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
   import cucumber.api.SnippetType;
   import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

   @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
   @CucumberOptions(
           plugin = { "json:target/test_results/cucumber.json"}, 
           features = { "src/main/resources/ui/features" },
        tags ={"@Dev,@tagteacher"},
           snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE

           )

   public class CucumberRunnerTest {

       public static void tearDown(){
           WebController.closeDeviceDriver();
       }
   }

   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   userstoryteacher1.feature file :-

   @TestStory
   Feature: Teachers timesheet need to be filled
     I want to use this template for my feature file

     Background: 

     Scenario Outline: Open Webpage
       Given User Open teacher application with given <ENDPOINT> 
       And   Login into application with given <USERNAME> and <PASSWORD>
       And User clicks on teacher submission link

       @DEV
       Examples: 
         | endpoint                       | USERNAME | PASSWORD    |
         | http://teachersheetdev.ggn.com | sdrdev| aknewdev|



       @QA
       Examples: 
         | endpoint                      | USERNAME | PASSWORD    |
         | http://teachersheetqa.ggn.com | sdrqa | aknewdev|
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   userstoryteacher2.feature file :-

   Feature : I'm at the teachers page

   @tagteacher
   Scenario: Open app home page and click the button
   Given I'm at the teachersheet homepage
   When User clicks Add Task button
   Then User should see the tasks schedule
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber is designed so that you can't link scenarios or feature files together. Each scenario should be run as an independent 'test' that starts from the beginning.

Programming with feature files is a terrible anti-pattern. Instead push the programming down into the step definition layer, or better yet into helpers that the step definitions use.

If you want to get the best out of Cucumber you need to use it to only express WHAT is being done and WHY its important. From your example this seems to be all about teachers filling in their timesheets so your scenarios should be things like

`Scenario: Fill in timesheet
  Given I am a teacher 
  And I am logged in 
  When I fill in my timesheet
  Then I should see my timesheet has been saved.`

You set up state in your Givens, and you build helper methods with each scenario you create, so that future scenarios can set up state easily. For example `Given I am a teacher` might be something like

```
def 'Given I am a teacher' do
  teacher = create_new_teacher;
  register_teacher(teacher)
  return teacher
end
```

Which is building on previous scenarios to register new teachers. If you follow this pattern you can have simple scenarios with a single Given that do vast amounts of setup just using a single method call. This is much better than linking several feature files together!!